# Find $\oint_{| z|=1}\frac{\log \mid \zeta(\frac{z}{z-1})\mid}{z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Evaluate
$$
\oint_{\left\vert z\right\vert\ =\ 1}
\log\left(\left\vert
\zeta\left(\frac{z}{z - 1}\right)\right\vert\right)
\,{\mathrm{d}z \over z}
$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the analytic continuation of Riemann zeta function which is analytic except for a simple pole at $s = 1$.

MY TRY-
Define $f(z)=\frac{\log \left| \zeta(\frac{z}{z-1})\right|}{z}$

Poles of $f(z)$ are $z=0$.

R=Residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$.

R$=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} (z-0) f(z)$

R= $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}  \log \left|\zeta(\frac{z}{z-1})\right|  $

$\zeta(0)=-1/2 $ gives,

R$=\log\left(\left| \frac{-1}{2}\right|\right)=-\log \ 2$

By Cauchy's Residue Theorem,

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\log \left| \zeta(\frac{z}{z-1})\right|}{z}dz=-2\pi i \log \ 2$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Another tiem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944738/oint-mid-z-mid-1-frac-log-mid-zeta-frac-z2z21-midzdz-0

Comment: @Tito Is my answer correct?

Comment: @Tito Please answer .

Comment: No it is a nonsense. $\log \zeta(z/(z-1))$ is not meromorphic.

Comment: @reuns Why it is not meromorphic? See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=poles+of+log+modulus%28%28zeta%28z%2F%28z-1%29%29%29%29

Comment: For obvious reasons.

Comment: @reuns But wolfram alpha says it has no poles

Comment: @reuns Please point out any singularity.

Comment: @reuns Please answer this is very important for my PhD

Comment: I doubt so, you'd have to learn the basic of complex analysis and the theory of $\zeta(s)$, there are plenty of books, follow them!

Comment: @Shekhar Suman if this is for your PhD then take advice from your supervisor or guide

Answer (score 2):

$g(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}$ is biholomorphic $\Bbb{C}-1$ to $\Bbb{C}-1$ and $|z|<1$ to $\Re(s)<1/2$.

$g(g(z))=z$ thus $\zeta( g(z))$ is analytic on $|z|<1$ with some zeros at $g(-2n)$ and at the $g(\rho),\Re(\rho)<1/2$.

**$\log \zeta(g(z))$ has some logarithmic branch points there.**

Then apply [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula).

For $r<1$

$$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=r} \log |\zeta(g(z))| \frac{dz}z=  \log |\zeta(0)|-\sum_{g(-2n)<r} \log \frac{g(-2n)}{r} - \sum_{g(\rho)<r} \log \frac{|g(\rho)|}{r}$$
so that
$$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=r} \log |\zeta(g(z))| \frac{dz}z= \infty$$

Comment: Will the contour integral be $-\infty$? I have to prove it to be zero

Comment: Why would it be zero. And it is $+\infty$

Comment: But what for the case $|z|=1$??

Comment: Your function is not $L^1(|z|=1)$. How do you want to integrate it on $|z|=1$.

Comment: But for using JENSENS THEOREM we require that $\zeta(\frac{z}{z-1})$ to be non zero on the boundary of $\mid z \mid =1$? . But on the boundary Re(z/(z-1))=1/2. So f has infinitely many zeros on the boundary as zeta has infinitely many zeros on the critical line.Please reply.

Comment: I am not applying it to $|z|=1$ but to $|z|=1-\epsilon$

Comment: But What if $\mid z \mid =1$? Any other attack to the problem? Please reply

Comment: Are $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=r} \log |\zeta(g(z))| \frac{dz}z$$ and $$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=1} \log |\zeta(g(z))| \frac{dz}z$$ same??

Comment: Why did you delete the other question ? It showed that here the RH criterion is from $\lim_{r\to 1^+}$ not from $\lim_{r\to 1^-}$.

Comment: I did'nt delete it. Please explain what do you mean by this? Please elaborate your last comment.

Comment: Also Zeta has infinitely many zeros on the critical line. But to apply JENSEN'S FORMULA number of zeros must be finite.